# Prove distributive law of multiplication over addition functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I'm currently on a beginner's course of haskell and lambda calculus and I'm unsure of how to do the following exercise:

Using the following definitions of (+) and (*) operations in haskell, prove:

1)The distributive law of the (*) over the (+)

```
(∀m⇓,n⇓,k⇓::N) (m+n) * k = m * k + n * k
```

Definitions:

```
(+) :: N -> N -> N
(+) = \m n -> case m of { 0 -> n; S(y) -> S(y+n)}

(*) :: N -> N -> N
(*) = \m n -> case m of { 0 -> 0; S y -> n + (y*n)}
```

My idea was to do what I did for a previous exercise, prove for each possible case of m. The difference is that the exercise I did was for Boolean type, which can only be true or false and this is a natural, so my guess was to do the proof for the cases m = 0 and m = S(y)

I easily managed to prove the equality for m = 0 but got stuck when doing it for m = S(y)

Case m = 0

```
(0 + n) * k =? 0 * k + n * k
Left side:
(0 + n) * k = (case 0 of {0->n;Sy->...}) * k
= n * k
Right side:
0 * k + n * k = (case 0 of {0->0;Sy->...}) + (n * k)
= 0 + (n * k) = (case 0 of {0->(n*k);Sy->...}) = n * k (equal to the left side)
```

Case m = S(y)

```
(Sy + n) * k =? Sy * k + n * k
Left side:
(case Sy of {0->...;Sy->S(y+n)}) * k = S(y+n) * k
= case Sx of {0->...;Sx-> k + k * (y+n)
Right side:
Sy * k + n * k = (case Sy of {0->...;Sy->k + k*y}) + n * k
= k + k*y + n * k (Point at which I got stuck)
```

(...) Stands for irrelevant code

On a side question, what exactly does the arrow down ⇓ on ∀m⇓ mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tell us what you did and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sure, just added the part for m = 0 and currently adding my attempt for m = Sy

Comment: The arrow ⇓ probably means: for every finite, non-bottom value. Consider that in Haskell you can define: `n :: Nat; n = S n` which is an "infinite number". And also: `loop :: Nat; loop = loop` which is a divergent computation of type `Nat`.  If you substitute this kind of values into that equation the equation may not hold.

Comment: Thank you @Bakuriu that was actually my guess, non-bottom value but I was unsure, thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are simply forgetting to apply the inductive hypothesis:

```
(Sy + n) * k =? Sy * k + n * k
Left side:
(case Sy of {0->...;Sy->S(y+n)}) * k = S(y+n) * k
= case Sx of {0->...;Sx-> k + k * (y+n)
( inductive hypothesis; we know that k * (y+n) = k*y + k*n)
= k + k*y + k*n
Right side:
Sy * k + n * k = (case Sy of {0->...;Sy->k + k*y}) + n * k
= k + k*y + n * k
```

Remember: you were providing by induction on the first argument of `+` that `(m+n)*k == m*k + n*k`. You proved the base case `(0+n)*k` so when proving the inductive case you assume to know that `(y+n)*k == y*k + n*k` for up to a certain value of `y` and you want to prove that `(S(y) + n)*k == S(y)*k + n*k`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that the reason why I didn't thought of this before is because I never intended to use induction on the first place. But yeah it works perfectly, thanks again